# Does ASP.NET Core BundlerMinifier.Core support .net 4.5.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The default `ASP.NET Core` template project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.1.258",
 ...
 }

 "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
   }
  },
```

The server I am deploying to only has `.NET 4.5.1` so I replace the above frameworks section with

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { }
},
```

but then I get the following build error in my ASP.net Core RTM application

> Error NU1002  The dependency BundlerMinifier.Core 2.1.258 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1. project.json

Does BundlerMinifier.Core support .net 4.5.1?

Comment: You shouldn't use .NET 4.5.1 anyways, it's support cycle ended January this year: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/ Also when you create a new ASP.NET Core project you can choose from .NET Core and .NET Framework templates. Later one comes with the appropriate framesections

Comment: If all the other asp.net core libraries support 4.5.1 despite ASP.NET CORE only being released recently, then surely the one library that was added at the 11th hour should do  too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into BundlerMinifier.Core [project.json](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/blob/master/src/BundlerMinifier.Core/project.json) file, you will find only `"netcoreapp1.0"` and `"net452"`, so right now the answer is "no".

Should work if you can upgrade your project to .NET 4.5.2

Comment: To update the .net framework is a big deal. I don't have the authority to just tell them .net framework has to be updated on a production server as it can impact many production systems